# Java. Привести массив byte[ ] к double, float и short.

Tags: java, преобразование, преобразование-типов

Есть моделька, в ней три поля:

```
private double timeStamp;
private float duration;
private short scoreBits;
```

Есть массив байтов:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[14];
```

Задача следующая: нужно первые 8 байтов сэтнуть в поле `double` моей модели, следующие 4 - в `float`, следующие 2 - в `short`.

И я вообще не понимаю как это сделать. help me plz

Comment: ваш вопрос не понятен, поэтому ловите тревогу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как то так:

```
    byte[] bytes=new byte[14];

    double myDouble=ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getDouble(0);
    float myFloat=ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getFloat(8);
    short myShort=ByteBuffer.wrap(bytes).getShort(12);
```

Comment: последняя строка getShort, и получается что в первом случае он прочитает все биты от 0, а нужно только 8, во втором с 8, но опять же до конца, а нужно только 4, ну вот последние 2 правильно

Comment: Он прочитает ровно столько сколько надо - для double прочтет только первые 8 ну и т.д.

Comment: а, понял, смотрит на размер переменной

Comment: Спасибо! То, что было нужно :)

Answer (score 3):

Можно воспользоваться `ByteBuffer`

```
ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes , 0, 8)).getDouble();
ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes , 8, 12)).getFloat();
ByteBuffer.wrap(Arrays.copyOfRange(bytes , 12, 14)).getShort(); //index from - включает, а вот to не включается
```

Comment: попробую ближе к ночи - отпишусь!

Comment: не будет, getDouble возвращает примитвный тип

Comment: Но с индексами копирования я возможно напутал

Comment: а зачем вам индексы, если можно один раз завернуть в буфер, а потом на этом буфере последовательно вызвать геты?